# floating div problem in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float, background-image

I'm trying to use a second background image with a floated div but it doesn't work in IE6 & 7

I'm aware that the floating div's is a pain in ***** in IE7 and lower versions but I really need to make it work.

here is the code I'm using

```
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-top:0px; margin-right:0px;" topmargin="0"       rightmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<div id="bg2" style="float:right; top:0px; width:450px; height:151px; margin-right:0px; padding-right:0px; font-size:1px; overflow:visible; background-image:url(images/back2.jpg);"></div>

<center>

<div style="position:relative; top:0px; width:1050px; margin:0px; padding:0px; vertical-align:top; text-align:left;">
....(huge div container)...
```

I also tried to remove width attribute from the div which contains 2nd background image, then get the windows size and add the difference to the container div as left attribute with Jquery. It worked fine in all IE versions but this time not on Chrome

[here is a print screen](http://orcunerdogdu.com/cayirhan/prntscr.jpg)

any ideas please?

Comment: Why are you floating the #bg2 to the right?
Instead you can align the <body> to the right and get rid of that float! That would fix it.

Comment: I was trying to place to container the center of the page, sorry I should mention it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..well actually I think I found my solution.

I was trying to align the container to center

I knew if there is not enough space for divs to fit in window, causing the problem in IE6 & 7, so I used Jquery css property to determine width of the floated background image div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(document).width() > 1050){          //Container's width:1050px
        var wd = document.body.clientWidth;
        wd = Math.round((wd-1050)/2); 
        $("#bg2").css("width" , wd);
        $("#container").css("left" , wd);
    }
});
</script>
```

and the html...

```
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<p align="right">
<div id="bg2" style="position:absolute; float:right; top:0px; right:0px; height:151px; margin:0px; padding:0px; font-size:1px; overflow:visible; background-image:url(images/back2.jpg);"></div>
<div id="container" style="position:absolute; top:0px; width:1050px; margin:0px; padding:0px; vertical-align:top; text-align:left;">
....(huge div container container)....
```